# Powershell universal error logging with &{} 2>> and trap {}

Tags: powershell, exception, error-handling

I have been trying to come up with a better solution to error management than what I do now. Current practice is to test as much as possible to avoid errors, then try/catch and log exceptions. The problem is that that only works when I KNOW there's a possibility of an exception. What I have been trying to find is a way to have some sort of generic exception trap, that logs those exceptions with enough detail to actually troubleshoot.

What I have come up with is this

```
$errorLog = "$env:temp\errors.log"

# main
&{

# productive code here

} 2>> $errorLog

trap {
    Out-File -InputObject $psItem.Exception.Message -FilePath $errorLog -Append
    Out-File -InputObject $psItem.ScriptStackTrace -FilePath $errorLog -Append
    Out-File -InputObject '' -FilePath $errorLog -Append
}
if (([System.IO.FileInfo]::new($errorLog)).Length -eq 0) {
    Remove-Item $pxToolsErrorLog
} else {
    Write-Host 'Errors'
}
```

This

```
&{
}
```

defines the main code block, and `2>> $pxToolErrorLog` redirects standard errors in that code block to the log file.
The Trap outputs unhandled exceptions to the same log.
And the final conditional looks to see if I logged any errors, deletes the log if not, and let's me know if I did.

I have only played with this in a test scenario, but I am looking to implement it with a utility I am working on now, and I wonder if there is something I am missing that argues against this approach? Mostly because I am self taught, and regularly do silly things that I later discover are a bad idea, and I have never seen this approach or anything like it mentioned in the MANY blog posts and SO threads and such that I have read on the topic. It seems unlikely to me that I really did blunder in to something both new and better. So, does anyone see anything in this simple example that screams "No!!!!" ? Or something that makes the Spidey sense tingle? Or even just a bit of a code smell I am missing? Other than "You really SHOULD know what might cause an exception!" because I know that, and I am trying to learn that, but I want something a bit more robust to help in the meantime. I should mention that the ultimate goal is to use it in a program that will have MANY thousands of lines of code, and also use classes over functions to the extent possible, in no small part because I am sick and tired of chasing pipeline pollution issues and would prefer the rigor of types. So, any issues related to classes and scaling are especially pertinent.

Also, to clarify, I would STILL do things like test to see if a file exists before doing anything with that file, and also try/catch wherever I know there's potential for exceptions. I am just looking to get a log, with line numbers and other details, for anything I miss. Then I can address those issues with tests or try/catch. But that does raise a question in my mind, could this be a viable option for development, but SHOULD be removed for production code? Or is it safe/performant enough to keep in production code, with something more elegant than just dumping `Errors` to the console if errors occurred?

Comment: One problem I see with this approach is that the logged errors are missing context. Usually it is the context that lets you track down a problem, not solely an isolated error message. In large scripts I'm using a similar approach, but I capture _every_ output using `& { } *>&1 | MyFunctionWritesToConsoleAndLogFile`.  Within `{}` I'm using a `try{} catch{ Write-Error -EA Continue ... }` to write unhandled exception information to the error stream as well. This keeps errors in context for better debugging.

Comment: If you still like to have a file that contains a summary of only errors, you could test in `MyFunctionWritesToConsoleAndLogFile` if the type of current stream object is `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord` and write these to a separate file as well. This would give you a quick overview while you could still look up context in the full log.

Comment: @zett42 Good point about the redirect missing some context. The limiting factor there is that I also do a real time log for the user, with Write-Host. I know that's frowned upon, but in my case it actually works really well. And I wonder, how do you know you have had an error? I can see if anything got written to my error log, but if I am dumping all output there then it is guaranteed to have content.

Comment: To check if you had an error: `if( $error.Count ) { ... }`

Comment: @zett42 Aha, I hadn't thought of that being a true running count. I have a few things to try I see. In your scenario, how big is the code base? Is it large enough that you would expect to see a performance hit if there was going to be one? I may profile performance early in this exercise, but good to know if you already have a sense of impact.

Comment: 10..25k LOC. I try to be not too verbose, which is always a balancing act (performance plays a role, but more so my sanity, when browsing logs ;-)). Started using `Write-Host` everywhere and have now switched to `Write-Verbose` for library code. I still use `Write-Host` too, but only at top-level code where I can be sure that I really always want that logging.